# Load specific module from position in joomla

Tags: module, templates

I want to be able to load a specific module from a position in a Joomla template. I have more than one module assigned to that position for other templates but for this new template I only want to load for example a module by name, or a module by index from that position.

Is that possible using the jdoc:include tag? or is there any other way to make it?

An example of a classic template position load that I use:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" style="xhtml" name="maintop-a" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Documentation says :

> Module
>
> ```
> <jdoc:include type="module" name="breadcrumbs" title="Breadcrumbs" />
> <jdoc:include type="module" name="mainmenu" title="Main Menu" />
> ```
>
> This element renders a single module given by the name and title
>   attributes: name should match module type (mod_breadcrumbs and
>   mod_menu in the examples above) while title should be the module name
>   of the desired module. The module in question must be published and
>   accessible by the current user in order to become visible. Additional
>   attributes can be provided to control the layout and appearance of the
>   module, if supported.

Is that what you need?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try a custom html module with the following: `{loadposition your-position-here}`?
For example:

```
{loadposition header-x}
```

And you will load the modules in the position "header-x".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can use `JModuleHelper::getModule` to load any module by name:

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule( 'mainmenu', 'Key Concepts' );
$attribs['style'] = 'xhtml';
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule( $module, $attribs );
```

For example usage, take a look at [this documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/JModuleHelper/renderModule).

Answer (score 1):

try this simple plugin

http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/load-module-into-article

This plugin displays any module into an article.

Syntax in editor:

{module [63]}
where 63 is the id of the module you want to load.

I hope it will help you.